# Displaying information on map

Tags: r

Then I wrote the below code to display different regions of New York city.

```
 download.file(
    # I saved a version on my server so this script should work
    # even if the NYC planning department changes things around
  "http://www.rob-barry.com/assets/data/mapping/nypp_15b.zip",
 destfile = "nypp_15b.zip")
unzip(zipfile = "nypp_15b.zip")
# Now, load package to read the shapefile
library("rgdal")
# Read it into an sp object:
nypp <- readOGR("nypp_15b", "nypp")
# Take a look! sp works seamlessly with R's plotting function.
plot(nypp) 
download.file(
"http://www.nyc.gov/html/nypd/downloads/zip/analysis_and_planning  /2014_sqf_csv.zip", "2014_sqf_csv.zip")
unzip("2014_sqf_csv.zip")   
library("RColorBrewer") 
library("classInt")
library("rgdal")

saf2014 <- read.csv("2014.csv")
safpct <- as.data.frame(table(saf2014$pct))
colnames(safpct) <- c("pct", "stops")
merge.shpdf.df <- function(shpdf, df, by.shpdf, by.df) {shpdf@data <- data.frame(shpdf@data, df[match(shpdf@data[, by.shpdf], df[, by.df]), ]); return(shpdf)}
nypp.merge <- merge.shpdf.df(nypp, safpct, "Precinct", "pct")
pal <- brewer.pal(5, "YlOrRd")
fill.clr <- findColours(classIntervals(nypp.merge@data$stops,style = "pretty", n = 5), pal)
plot(nypp, col = fill.clr)
legend(
 "topleft",
  fill=attr(fill.clr, "palette"),
  legend=names(attr(fill.clr, "table")),
  bty = "n"
)
```

I have 2 questions:

1) How can I write the name of each region on the map?

2) I have data set like:

```
coord <- data.frame(object = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), pickuplong = 
               c(-73.93909 ,-73.94189 ,-73.93754,-73.91638,-73.92792,-73.88634),pickuplat =c(40.84408,40.83841,40.85311,40.84966,40.86284,40.85628))
```

How can I presents that how many of each object belongs to which region of New York city. (May be presenting some thing like heat map or ...)

Comment: I am getting error on the first line of your code.

Comment: This may or may not help you; but worth taking a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376213/show-the-value-of-a-geom-point-using-geom-text/44377044#44377044

Comment: @Masoud : which line? after downloading you should unzip the file in your path.

Comment: I realized that. First line is `nypp <- readOGR("nypp_15b", "nypp")`.

Comment: @Masoud : you right. first 2 lines are redundant. I removed them.

Comment: What's `nypp` now? in the `nypp.merge` line?

Comment: Run your lines once. You need an S4 class object if you're using `@`. Debug it and then re-post your answer. (You can hit delete, edit, and then undelete). Cheers.

Comment: @Masoud I updated the code. It is working for me. can you please try it?